# Issues with the update query SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

am writing a c# code in which am trying to update 4 of the 10 columns of the table. Here is my function type in which am sending arguments for the query:

```
public int checkout_visitor(int check_inn, int checkout, String time_out, String date_out, String cnic)
```

Now what happens is that i call this function somewhere in my program providing values in argument:

```
checkout_visitor(chk_in,chk_out,t_out,dt_out,idcardnum);
```

The query am using to update my columns is given by:

```
String query2 = " UPDATE visit_detail SET[check_in] = " + check_inn + "[check_out] = " + checkout + "[time_out] = " + time_out + "[date_out] =" + date_out + "where visit_detail.v_id = "+ v_idd;
```

Given me exception incorrect syntax near chkout. Where am i wrong?? is the syntax correct? how do i correct it?

code:

```
 public int checkout_visitor(int check_inn, int checkout, String time_out, String date_out, String cnic)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            String query = "select v_id from visitor where visitor.cnic=" + cnic;
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;
            visitor_id = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            int v_idd = Int32.Parse(visitor_id);
            String query2 = " UPDATE visit_detail SET[check_in] = " + check_inn + "[check_out] = " + checkout + "[time_out] = " + time_out + "[date_out] =" + date_out + "where visit_detail.v_id = " + v_idd;
            //String query2 = "UPDATE visit_detail SET [check_in] = " + check_inn + ",[check_out] = " + checkout + ",[time_out] = " + time_out + ",[date_out] =" + date_out + " where visit_detail.v_id = " + v_idd; 
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query2;
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you forgot space between SET and check_in SET[check_in] => SET [check_in]

Comment: Please consider using parameters instead of blindly concatenating string values. Are any of these user-enterable? I'd to enter the value `1234'); DROP TABLE visit_detail;--` for my ID card number: http://xkcd.com/327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

1.you are not seperating the Parameters properly using comma `,`  .
2.you are not giving the sapace between `SET` and `check_in` parameter.

Try This:

```
String query2 = "UPDATE visit_detail SET [check_in] = " + check_inn + ",[check_out] = " + checkout + ",[time_out] = '" + time_out + "',[date_out] ='" + date_out + "' where visit_detail.v_id = "+ v_idd;
```

Comment: @user3081555: try my solution, just replace query2 provided in my answer it works.

Comment: @user3081555: edited answer by enclosing date values in single quotes. check now

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the resulting query? It seems to me you're missing some comma, but you should print (and post) the resulting query to have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: " UPDATE visit_detail SET[check_in] = 0[check_out] = 1[time_out] = 04:43 PM[date_out] =12-9-2013where visit_detail.v_id = 2"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ',' between the column names.
Its like Update Table Set col1=3,col2='test'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `query2` string will be something along the lines:

```
UPDATE visit_detail SET[check_in] = " 1[check_out] = 2[time_out] = some time[date_out] =some datewhere visit_detail.v_id = 5
```

So you can already see that there's `datewhere` that is incorect, there are also no `'` characters around string parameters, and no commas between parameters.

Quick fix to that would be:

```
String query2 = String.Format("UPDATE visit_detail SET [check_in]={0}, [check_out]={1}, [time_out]='{2}', [date_out]='{3}' where visit_detail.v_id={4};", check_inn, checkout, time_out, date_out, v_idd);
```

But this is still not valid. If `time_out` contains `'` characters, you'll again receive an error.

What you should really use is this:
[SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This is a proper way of passing paramters to your command, all the problems will be taken care of for you.